# yoast sitemap xml

Tags: plugin-wp-seo-yoast

the end results contains some empty lines and that's an invalid xml cause.

I wanted to find out where those extra lines comes from but there are 100s of places to look into.

Is there a way I can hook into the sitemap generation's begin and end points and set up output buffer and solve my problem that way?

If so, does anyone know how I can hook into the yoast plugin's as such?

Comment: If it's possible then it'll probably be well documented on the YOAST site - and if it isn't, I'd recommend asking in their support forums.  Third Party plugins are off-topic here.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

This question will likely be marked 'off-topic' because it's asking about a plugin, WordPress SEO by Yoast. I suggest you explore Yoast's own documentation first - see https://developer.yoast.com/features/xml-sitemaps/

They also have a forum on the WordPress.org site where you can ask questions: https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/wordpress-seo/